# Division safe from overflow for fixedpoint

Tags: c++, c, mathematics

So I was investigating overflow safe division for a class that uses an int64 member with a given RESOLUTION ( 10000 ) for the fractional part. To preserve precision in the fractional part during an easy division you would multiply by the resolution first, which if the number is large enough results in an overflow. I came up with an algorithm to divide without overflow but I think it could probably be optimized better, I just can't see at first glance how:

```
int64 divideOverflowSafe( const int64 Lhs, const int64 Rhs ) const
{
    // The idea here is simple, split Lhs * RESOLUTION / Rhs into two separate divisions to avoid the multiplication by RESOLUTION and thus avoid the overflow
    const int64 FracPart = Lhs % RESOLUTION;
    const int64 DecPart = Lhs - FracPart;

    // Just dividing the integral part means there's already an inherent resolution buffer for precision. We then need to also calculate the remainder, which is small enough that it can be multiplied by RESOLUTION ( and needs to be, to maintain precision )
    const int64 Res1 = DecPart / Rhs;
    const int64 Res1Remainder = ( DecPart % Rhs ) * RESOLUTION / Rhs;

    // The fractional part is small enough to be multiplied by RESOLUTION, again for precision reasons
    const int64 Res2 = FracPart * RESOLUTION / Rhs;

    // At the end we add everything back together to obtain the result
    const int64 Res = Res1 * RESOLUTION + Res1Remainder + Res2;
    return Res;
}
```

Comment: Is m_nVal and b.m_nVal supposed to be Lhs and Rhs?

Comment: @AbhayAravinda sorry, fixed. Yes